# Filtering Array Not Working After the First Call

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing an issue with filtering an array in Angular. In my component, I have a select to choose the season of a TV series and a list of associated episodes. The filter seems to work correctly only on the first call, but afterward, the array remains empty, even though in the console log, I can see that every time I change the season, I receive the data from seriesService.giro, which contains all the episodes of the series. However, it doesn't go through the filter and fails to display them on the screen after the first time.
The filter works because if I change the value of the variable that initializes the select, it manages to filter without problems, but only the first time.

Here is my current code:

```
export class SchedaFilmComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedSeason: number = 1;
  filteredEpisodes: any[] = [];

  constructor(public seriesService: SeriesServiceService, private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onSeasonChange();
  }

  onSeasonChange() {
    this.filteredEpisodes = this.filterEpisodesBySeason(this.selectedSeason);
    console.log('Filtered Episodes:', this.filteredEpisodes);
    console.log('Original Episodes:', this.seriesService.giro);
  }

  filterEpisodesBySeason(season: number): any[] {
    console.log('Filter episodes by season:', season);

    const filteredEpisodes = this.seriesService.giro.filter(episode => episode.seasonNumber === season);
    console.log('Filtered Episodes:', filteredEpisodes);

    return filteredEpisodes;
  }
}
<!-- ... (other HTML code) -->
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedSeason" (change)="onSeasonChange()">
  <option *ngFor="let season of seriesService.seasonList" [value]="season">
    Season {{ season }}
  </option>
</select>

<ul class="episodes-list">
  <li *ngFor="let episode of filteredEpisodes">
    Season {{ episode.seasonNumber }} - Episode {{ episode.episodeNumber }}: {{ episode.title }}
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- ... (other HTML code) -->
```

Comment: you may not want "const filteredEpisodes".... try with "this.filteredEpisodes".  (You don't have to return anything from that function, just set it there and call this.filterEpisodesBySeason(this.selectedSeason); You may also want to check type of returned option value... right now you have === in the filter, you might just use == instead in case the option value is actually inferred as a string.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to keep an original copy of the episodes and apply the filter on this copy without directly editing it. Here's an example of how you might change the code:

```js
export class SchedaFilmComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedSeason: number = 1;
  episodes: any[] = [];
  filteredEpisodes: any[] = [];

  constructor(public seriesService: SeriesServiceService, private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.episodes = this.seriesService.giro; // Store a copy of the original episodes
    this.onSeasonChange();
  }

  onSeasonChange() {
    this.filteredEpisodes = this.filterEpisodesBySeason(this.selectedSeason);
    console.log('Filtered Episodes:', this.filteredEpisodes);
    console.log('Original Episodes:', this.episodes);
  }

  filterEpisodesBySeason(season: number): any[] {
    console.log('Filter episodes by season:', season);

    const filteredEpisodes = this.episodes.filter(episode => episode.seasonNumber === season);
    console.log('Filtered Episodes:', filteredEpisodes);

    return filteredEpisodes;
  }
}
```

Comment: It does exactly the same thing as before; it works only on the first load. I don't understand why. I've tried so many ways

Comment: can you share the complete code on stackBlitz?